# the form input does not return a vlalue...why?

Tags: php, html

I am using this code to try and submit a value via form but it doesn't seem to submit anything...
how can I solve this problem?
Is this code wrong?
I am using this code to try and submit a value via form but it doesn't seem to submit anything...
how can I solve this problem?
Is this code wrong?

```
  <?php
    extract($_POST);
if($_POST['finish']){
        <script>alert($_POST['cname']);</script>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="content">
            <form method="post" action="a.php">
            <h1>New car</h1>
            <p>Here you can add a new car</p>
            <div id="box">
                <div class="box-top">car</div>
                    <div class="box-panel">
                    <div class="form">
                    <p class="name">
                            <input type="text" name="cname" placeholder="car 
                </p>
                        <p class="text">
                            <textarea name="text" name="cardesc" placeholder="short descrition"/></textarea>
                        </p>
                        <p class="submit">
                            <input type="submit" id="next" value="Next" />

                        </p>
                </div>
                    <progress id="pb" value="0" max="100" style="width:100%;margin-top:2%"></progress>
                    <div id="percent"></div>
                    </div>

            </div>
                <div id="box2">
                <div class="box-top">Highlights</div>
                    <div class="box-panel" style="background-color:#fff;padding:15px;color:#ccc">
                      <div class="form">
                        <p class="name">
                            <input type="text" name="hname"  placeholder="Highlights title"/>
                             <span class="button">Choose a Photo</span>
                            <span class="file-wrapper"><input type="file" name="hfile" value="Highlights image"/>

                             </span>
                        </p>

                        <p class="text">
                            <textarea name="hdesc" placeholder="short descrition about this Highlights"/></textarea>
                        </p>
                        <p class="submit">
                            <input type="button" id="add" value="add more Highlights" style="width:30%;" />
                        </p>
                        <p class="submit">
                            <input type="button" id="previous" value="previous"/>

                            <input type="button" id="next2" value="next"   style="margin-left:11%;"/>                       
                        </p>

                    <progress id="pb" value="20" max="100" style="width:100%;margin-top:2%"></progress>
                    <div id="percent"></div>
                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>
                </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've just mixed Javascript and PHP together! your input tag is not closed.

Comment: `<?php
if(isset($_POST['finish'])){
       echo '<script>alert('.$_POST['cname'].');</script>';
}
?>`

Comment: I closed it  but the problem does not solve

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors:

```
extract($_POST);
```

This isn't an error, but it is very bad practise. You are allowing the user to splurge arbitrary variables into your program. You aren't actually using any of those variables anyway, so just don't do that. Use `$_POST['something']` to get at the data when you need it.

```
if($_POST['finish']){
```

Your HTML doesn't have an input named `finish` so this will never be true. You might want to look for `cname` instead.

```
<script>alert($_POST['cname']);</script>
```

You've started writing HTML without leaving PHP mode.

You're also trying to inject user input directly into the page, which renders you vulnerable to XSS.

You're also failing to generate the syntax for a JavaScript string literal, so the value would be treated as a variable.

```
?>
<script>
  alert(<?php echo json_encode($_POST['cname']); ?>);
</script>
```